# Equalizer UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation

Tags: java, android, equalizer

This is my equalizer class, and for a long time it worked without any problem,but now i'm getting this error.

P.S yesterday i flashed a custom rom on my phone, could that be the problem?
Because on another device it works fine.

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
   at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.checkStatus(AudioEffect.java:1299)
   at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.setBandLevel(Equalizer.java:223)
```

**My code**

```
verticalSeekbar[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                    short newLevel = (short)(progress + lowerEqualizerBandLevel);
                    short band = (short)seekBar.getTag();
                    bandLevels[band] = newLevel;
                    if (mEqualizer != null) {
                        mEqualizer.setBandLevel(band, newLevel);
                    }
                    slider_value[band].setText((progress + lowerEqualizerBandLevel) / 100 + " dB");

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
            slider_labels[i].setText(formatBandLabel(freq_range));

        }
```

**EDIT**
Im certain that the problem is the custom rom because on stock roms it works fine.

What could be the reason it throws UnsupportedOperationException on custom roms?